# PHP Button Needed to call a function

Tags: php, button

How do I turn the below code into a button on my page?  It works the way its written but I don't like that it's a hyperlink. I would prefer it to be a button.

```
echo " <form>
<a href='test.php?id=$key&do=unfollow'>unfollow</a>
</form>";
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how buttons interact with PHP?

Comment: do u want this action in javascript? is it ok for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo " <form action='test.php' method='GET'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$key'/>
<input type='submit' name='do' value='unfollow'/>
</form>";
```

Comment: This approach worked for me.  Thanks mgraph.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your link does not have to be inside a `FORM`. This is because you don't have user input, and because you are using `GET`.

Second: Use `CSS` to style the hyperlink and make it look like a `button`.